# Scaling ECS EC2 instances when a task cannot be placed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am using an ECS cluster for Jenkins agents/slaves with the [Jenkins ECS plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Amazon+EC2+Container+Service+Plugin).

The plugin places a ECS Task when a job requests a build-node. Now I want to scale the EC2 instances in a Autoscaling Group associated with the ECS Cluster according to  the demand.

1. The jenkins is often idle. In this case, I do not want there to be any instances in the autoscaling group.
2. If a node (and therefore an ECS task) is requested and cannot be placed, I want to add an EC2 instance to the autoscaling group.
3. If an instance is idle and shortly before an billing hour, I want that instance to be removed.

The 3. point can be accomplished by a cronjob on the EC2 instances that regularly checks if the conditions are met and removes the EC2 instance.

But how can I accomplish the 2. point? I am unable to create a cloudwatch alarm that triggers, if a task cannot be placed.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Not really, I implemented a separate "agent" on the jennkins instance which manages the EC2 instances for us

Answer (score 1):

A rather hacky way to achieve this: You could use a Lambda function to detect when a service has `runningCount + pendingCount < desiredCount` for more than X seconds. (I have not tested this yet.)
Similar solutions are proposed [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/6bmrxj/container_instance_scaling_in_ecs/).

There does not seem to be a proper solution to scale only when tasks cannot be placed. Maybe AWS wants us to over-provision our clusters, which might be good practice for high availability, but not always the best or cheapest solution.

Answer (score 1):

When a task cannot be placed it means that placing that task in your ECS cluster would exceed either your MemoryReservation or CPUReservation.  You could set up Cloudwatch alarms for one or both of these ECS metrics and an auto scaling policy that will add and remove EC2 instances in your ECS cluster.

This, in combination with an auto scaling policy that scales your ECS services on the ecs:service:DesiredCount dimension *should* be enough to get you adding the underlying EC2 instances your ECS cluster requires.

For example your ScalingPolicy for an ECS Service might be "when we're using 70% of our allotted memory for this service, add 2 to the DesiredCount".  After adding 1 service task, your ECS Cluster MemoryReservation metric might bump up past an "80" threshold, at which point a Cloudwatch alarm would trigger for some threshold on ECS MemoryReservation, with an auto scaling policy adding another EC2 node, on which the 2nd task could now be placed.

Answer (score 1):

For those arriving after January 2020, the way to handle it now is probably Cluster Auto Scaling as documented here: "[Amazon ECS cluster auto scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cluster-auto-scaling.html)" with more info here: "[Deep Dive on Amazon ECS Cluster Auto Scaling](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/deep-dive-on-amazon-ecs-cluster-auto-scaling/))".

Essentially, ECS now handles *most* the heavy lifting. Not all, or I wouldn't be here looking for an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

For point 2, one way to solve this would be to autoscale when there is not enough cpu units for placing a new jenkins slave.

You should use the cpu reservation metric on the cluster to scale.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cloudwatch-metrics.html#cluster_reservation

Comment: That does not really solve point 2. I want the scale event to happen when a task cannot be placed. Not when it potentially cannot be placed: The reason is, that there are some tasks that need 12GB of Ram, which is almost a full EC2 instance. If I would scale like you suggest, I would always have an extra EC2 instance running. That I do not want.